Number of subjects for test-retest reliability estimates
I am designing a study aimed at evaluating the test-retest reliability of a certain sports endurance test, which I will calculate using an ICC(3,1) following Weir (2005).
I would like to have a rough idea of how many subjects I should enroll in my study in order to get reasonable intervals when estimating the ICC of my test.
Is there a way I can calculate something like this in advance?

The ICC is a correlation. How many samples you need will depend on what you think of as "reasonable" and also what size correlation you expect. Many stats packages (certainly R and SAS, but also others) will have canned programs to calculate this for various inputs. There are also online apps to do this. I prefer using a program that allows me to save the code that generated the output, but the apps should also work. (Also, the programs will let you output the solution for a range of N and r).
In R, one choice is pwr.r.test in the pwr package.

The formulae that you need (for transforming $F$ and $MSE$ into upper and lower CI's) are available in Table 7 of this paper:
McGraw, K. O., & Wong, S. P. (1996). Forming inferences about some intraclass correlation coefficients. Psychological Methods, 1(1), 30–46.
Here's the link to the paper on ResearchGate, as long as that stays active. The limiting factor for you will indeed be the number of participants, however, the variation in participants' scores at both timepoints will also be a factor (indeed, that's what is being captured).
However, the paper may not be extremely enlightening, as they do not discuss the case of test-retest reliability, but confine themselves to inter-rater reliability, consistency, and agreement.
Either way, you're dealing with a random-effects model, so the pwr package might not give you what you want.
